# In prometheus all target servers show as down with this error: dial tcp 10.7.17.11:9100: getsockopt: connection timed out

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubectl

I have configured the Node Exporter in Kubernetes and start monitoring using Prometheus, But in Prometheus all servers are showing as down with the error below:

> Get http://10.7.17.11:9100/metrics: dial tcp 10.7.17.11:9100:
>   getsockopt: connection timed out

Can anyone help why it is showing down ?

Comment: Can you share a little bit more of contexts? some yaml of your deployment or services?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure firewall is not blocking port 9100. 
Try to curl this URL from other nodes and from the prometheus pod